# C - Break while loop when typing the number 0 into a vector

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have this simple code that inserts the number entered in the terminal at the position of the vector at each loop.

```
int main() 
{
    int vector[5];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Number: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &vector[i]);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My question is how I break the loop as soon as I type the number 0.

For example, imagine that my vector have 50 positions and I type 10 positions with positive integers numbers and now I want the loop ends when I enter zero and the rest of the 40 positions remain blank.

I imagine it's with the while loop, but I could not even get close to the result I want.

Comment: check the value before before you write it to `vector[i]`. If it's 0, then `break`.. or keep what you've got and simply add `if (vector[i] == 0) break;`. Depends on if you what 0 to make it into `vector[i]` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define MAX_SIZE (5)

int main() 
{
    int vector[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
    int i;

    memset(vector, 0xFF, sizeof(vector)); //sets all vector[i] to -1 on init;
    for (i = 0; (i < MAX_SIZE) && (i?vector[i-1]:1) ; i++) //you can add the condition to break from the for loop here.  This is more complicated but its just for demonstration.
    {
        printf("Number: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &vector[i]);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The above sample code demonstrates the using the for loops conditional expression as a means to break the loop.  The ternary in there prevents the i=0 case resulting in an out of bounds index, due to the way you structured your loop.  The better/more readable way is below:

```
#define MAX_SIZE (5)

int main() 
{
    int vector[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
    int i;

    memset(vector, 0xFF, sizeof(vector)); //sets all vector[i] to -1 on init;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Number: %d\n", i);
        scanf_s("%d", &vector[i]);
        if(vector[i] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    //system("pause");
    printf("Broke the loop when i was %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

The difference between the two besides readability is that i will be incremented one extra time in the first one.  Also, make sure to initialize all the variables you declare (all your vector elements are stack garbage, the 0xFF memset assigns them all to -1).

Comment: {-1} will assign vector[0] = -1; vector[1] = 0; vector[2] = 0; etc.  Every element that is not explicitly initialized in the array assignment is assigned to 0 by default.

So, {0} assigns 0 to every element, then the memset assigns each byte 0xFF which (because they're signed ints) ends up being -1.

Comment: If  you use memset anyhow, why even bother to initialize the array?

Comment: @GermanNerd in the second example its unused and redundant, and its also redundant in the first.  I always initialize anything i declare as a habit and you cant initialize an array of #defined SIZE to anything besides {0} maintainably.  If SIZE were to change someone would have to change the initialization {-1,-1,-,1.etc} to have the new SIZE -1s.